# My game relies heavily on globals, but also gives me syntaxwarning even though the game won't work without them

Tags: python

How can I make this so that it just doesn't rely on globals altogether? When I run my game, it gives me a syntaxwarning, but my game won't work without the globals.

http://pastebin.com/pnzutun6

Comment: Paste the relevant code here Ratchet! Try http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: his code is too big, i think the link was a much better option

Comment: @letsc if the code is too long it should be cut down, per the link Mathemats has provided. Off-site hosting is **not** acceptable here.

Comment: *"How can I make this so that it just doesn't rely on globals altogether?"* - with explicit function parameters and `return` values. I suggest you read a Python tutorial.

Comment: @jonrsharpe his code has `global` variables spread across the program. What would the best way be to show them, because just pasting a bunch of `global variablename` statements would not help one bit

Comment: @letsc frankly, the fundamental problem here is that this isn't a good question for SO. The answer is either my comment above, or rewriting the OP's whole code for them. If they just want to fix the error, a single reproducible example is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, like oxrock said, utilize OOP. The easier option (although perhaps not the best stylistically), would be to pass your stats as parameters to every one of your functions. The best way to do this would be via a dictionary:

```
stats = {'ponyattack': 0, 'health': 100, 'armor': 1, 'strength': 1, 'potion': 0, 'attack': 10, 'stamina': "N/A", 'shield': "lol, what shield?", 'hint': 3}
```

Define all your functions to take in stats as a parameter. If a function only needs one or two stats, pass them individually instead... it makes for better style.

Whenever you want to access a particular stat, you can call `stats['ponyattack']` or `stats['health']` or whatever else. You can also modify and add stats in the same way:

```
stats['health'] = stats['health'] + 1
stats['armor'] = 10
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) is some more info on dictionaries.

Comment: Classes also worked. Pardon this amateur-ish post. I was getting very desperate for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just skimming through your code I noticed that you don't seem to be utilizing OOP really at all. Convert some of those functions into classes and have the objects you create hold your current global variables that keep giving you problems.